# near "?" syntax error в sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Пытаюсь понять как работать с базами данных sqlite и надо вытащить из таблицы значение, при этом в where надо подставить перменную

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT preds FROM members WHERE memID = ?????????????????? """, (mem))
```

переменная mem имеет 18 символов как и количество "?", если это неправильно - это сделано из-за того что он жаловался на количество символов в переменной. Я не знаю почему выходит ошибка. Как это исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаки вопроса ставятся по числу переменных, соответственно должен быть только 1.

Скорее всего ошибка в этом ([источник](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)):

> In Python, a tuple containing a single value must include a comma. For example, ('abc') is evaluated as a scalar while ('abc',) is evaluated as a tuple.

Значит должно быть `(mem,)`

Comment: The current statement uses 1, and there are 18 supplied. ошибка

Comment: @5iqman, а если запятую добавить?

Comment: все спасибо, так еще неделю гадал бы